# Why didn't the abdication of the Nicholas Tsar II duing the Russian Revolution solve Russia's political and social problems?

Tags: russian-revolution

Why didn't the abdication of the  Nicholas Tsar II duing the Russian Revolution solve Russia's political and social problems?

Can you give examples using primary or secondary sources?

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to HSE. Which research did you do about this subject?

Comment: "Political and social problems" are rarely, if ever, caused by a single person.

Answer (score 2):

**Brief Answer (but also clarifying OP's premise of this question):**

Autocratic Russia under the Romanovs caused misery (lack of warmth, food, security, etc) during WW1. Abdication by **[Nicholas II to Michael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Duke_Michael_Alexandrovich_of_Russia#Abdication_of_Nicholas_II)** (his younger brother) **did not alleviate the problems faced by common folks**.

Michael quickly abdicated as well because the populace did not support the Tsarist institution anymore. In other words, the conditions for Russian workers' revolt was not simply the existence of the Tsarist autocracy per se (altho' they clearly were the symbols and hence had the blame for it). **It was the living conditions (daily life) of common folks (incl soldiers) who had to endure their contribution to WW1 as part of the** [**Entente**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Entente).

For very short read, see: G. J. Meyer, "*[A World Undone](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.com/books/113757/a-world-undone-by-g-j-meyer/9780553382402/)*" (2006), chapter 27, "*Revolution and Intervention*". Many more detailed and authoritative books exist on the Russian Revolution, covering both revolutions, February & October (of 1917). Armistice between *new* Russia (officially **[Russian SFSR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Soviet_Federative_Socialist_Republic)**) and Central Powers happened soon after, [December 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armistice_between_Russia_and_the_Central_Powers). Clearly the new Russian government was acutely aware of the cause of the revolutions, and so they exited the Great War very quickly.

(Welcome to the site).

Comment: You ignored the Kerensky government, which is what I read between the lines as the real subject of OP' s question. It's kind of misleading to talk about "the new Russian government" when you just mean Lenin's.

Comment: @Spencer And before Kerensky, it was Prince Lvov's Provisional Government. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Provisional_Government

Comment: @Spencer - In truth, there's so much more of course. Just to get new OP started was my intention, hence the *brief answer* with recommendation.